# sublime text: manually install package control

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

I cannot use the simple installation code because a proxy blocks my way out. Unfortunately, I just don't get the instructions on the webpage.

```
1. Click the Preferences > Browse Packages… menu
2. Browse up a folder and then into the Installed Packages/ folder
3. Download Package Control.sublime-package and copy it into the Installed Packages/ directory
4. Restart Sublime Text
```

What exactly does `2.` mean? I guess I literally don't understand what "Browse up a folder and then into..." means.

I did click on the `Browse Packages` menu and used the popup explorer window to create a folder in my documents directory called `Installed Packages`. But what's next? Since I am just in a regular Explorer window, it I don't see how sublime now knows about this folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. In Sublime Text, click the `Preferences > Browse Packages…` menu

- this opens Windows Explorer in the path `%AppData%\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`.

> 2. Browse up a folder

- go up one folder level, the equivalent of `cd ..` in the command prompt. So basically, you want to be in `%AppData%\Roaming\Sublime Text 3`.

  [image: Packages folder]

  You can do this using the breadcrumbs in the address bar - using the above image as a guide, click on `Sublime Text 3`. Alternatively, press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to go up a folder level. (Normally it will go back one history level, but in this case there is no history because it is a new Explorer window, so it will go up a directory in the folder hierarchy.)

> and then into the `Installed Packages` folder

- Double click on the `Installed Packages` folder to navigate into it.

> 3. Download `Package Control.sublime-package` and copy it into the `Installed Packages` directory

- So you will have a file called `Package Control.sublime-package` in the `%AppData%\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages` folder.

> 4. Restart Sublime Text

- Close ST and launch it again.

Comment: Ah, "browse up" as in "cd ..". That was the part I missed. Thanks a million!

Comment: On today's date (2019-03-11) the link on [packagecontrol.io](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) refers to a .zip file with the name of `Package Control.zip`. By changing the name to and file tipe to: `Package Control.sublime-package` it worked for me. Do not extract the .zip, change the name and file ending and then put it into `%AppData%\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages`

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users, for No. 2, you'll most likely see this. That is the Packages file

[image: image1]

To be able to browse up a folder and view the Installed Packages:

[image: The installed packages file]

Then from there, download using the link and put it in the installed package folder, there you go!

Comment: If possible, it is better to show the steps, instead of posting an image.